# Why is 'mime.types' required in Apaches' 'conf' directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server, php, dependencies

I have been running Apache for around 5 years now and am going through a streamlining of my site scripts.

In this process I removed all directories and files I didn't know a use of. In my server root directory, `/srv/`, these directories were:

- `man/`
- `build/`
- `icons/`
- `logs/`

In my configuration directory, these directories (and one file) were:

- `magic` (file)
- `extras/`

Unfortunately, my server would then not host a page when running `/bin/apachectl start`. After reinstalling combinations of the above files, I found that I needed `logs/` in my root directory for debugging issues outside of VirtualHost logs. I also found that I needed the file `/conf/mime.types`, which leads me to my question.

I understand this file maps between file extensions (.doc, .xlsx, .jpeg, etc), to 'Internet Media Types' (IMTs), but I'm not clear on why Apache needs these specified.

My experience using IMTs until now is in specifying them in html, so the receiver knows how to handle a file, and in my Apache configuration files, where I have used them so a receiver interprets a file a certain way, regardless of its extension - for example to ensure a download with a download button.

Why does removal of the `conf/mime.types` file prevent my server from correctly serving my files ? Why does Apache, run on my machine, not ask the wider system for the answers ? Is it that such a mapping is not built into the generic Apache source code ?

My best guess is that, as I am running my server on .php scripts, without this file, Apache does not know how to interpret my local .php files.

Any assistance in answering the above questions, possibly with specific reference to where I may learn more about the stability of Apache, would be appreciated.

Comment: “Why does Apache, run on my machine, not ask the wider system for the answers ? Is it that such a mapping is not built into the generic Apache source code ?” Because it needs mime types to translate and interpret files to be served. That’s it. It doesn’t get mime types from the larger system. It needs them because it needs them. That’s it.

Comment: That said: “…and am going through a streamlining of my site scripts. In this process I removed all directories and files I didn't know a use of.” Don’t fix things that aren’t broken. Stop doing this. You will not save space. You will only break things.

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm not clear on why Apache needs these specified"

The point is that Apache itself does not *need* to really know about
[MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)
types when serving files, because it can just send the files.
However, the browser or the recipient wouldn't know what to do with
these files without the MIME information that Apache adds into the
header of the downloaded file.

The file `mime.types` contains all the MIME type that are known to
Apache. These are used to create principally the very important
[Content-Type Header Field](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html)
that is transmitted inside the header that precedes the file itself:

> The Content-Type header field is used to specify the nature of the
> data in the body of an entity, by giving type and subtype identifiers,
> and by providing auxiliary information that may be required for
> certain types. After the type and subtype names, the remainder of the
> header field is simply a set of parameters, specified in an
> attribute/value notation. The set of meaningful parameters differs for
> the different types. The ordering of parameters is not significant.
> Among the defined parameters is a "charset" parameter by which the
> character set used in the body may be declared. Comments are allowed
> in accordance with RFC 822 rules for structured header fields.
>
> In general, the top-level Content-Type is used to declare the general
> type of data, while the subtype specifies a specific format for that
> type of data. Thus, a Content-Type of "image/xyz" is enough to tell a
> user agent that the data is an image, even if the user agent has no
> knowledge of the specific image format "xyz".

When the MIME type information is missing for a given file extension,
a modern version of Apache should still have some defaults for a `none`
type.

The `mime.types` file is only one of the very useful, even crucial,
files that Apache needs to do its job as a web-server.
Many of these files fulfill important functions, whose importance
is not clearly indicated. I suggest to leave these files and folder
as they are. The several bytes that you may economize by removing them,
will not compensate for the trouble that you may run into in the
future.